# Javascript working only after I open a modal

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

So I have a problem where my script for a filter/search list used to work, added a few lines of code to open a modal when a certain event occurs and now strangely when I go on my page, I can't use the search/filter list, but when I open the modal and close it, then I can use it..? It looks like it has to process the modal script first to be able to use the search/filter script.

I am working with Django and MySQL, here are the relevant lines of code:

.html ( first lines are about the search function, the second part is the modal and third block is the table used in the search/filter function and the conditions for opening the modal  )

```
      <div class="search-right">
        <input type="text" id="mySearchInput" placeholder= " Search a stock.." title="Stock Search" style="float:left">
      </div>

      {% if warning %}
        <div id="myModalAddaStock" class="modalAddaStock">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="closeAddaStock">&times;</span>
            <p>{{warning}} {% if stock_to_add %}{{stock_to_add}} {% endif %}{% if stock_to_replace %}{{stock_to_replace}} or {{flex}}{% endif %}</p>
          </div>
        </div>{% endif %}

  <div class="grid-itam-2bottom">

        <table id="myTable1" class="myTable"cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="100%">
          <tr class="stockheader">
            <th width="8%" style="text-align:center;">Symbol</th>
            <th width="35%"style="text-align:center">Company Name</th>
            <th width="8%" style="text-align:center">Sector</th>
            <th width="7%" style="text-align:center">Streak</th>
            <th width="12%"style="text-align:center">Market Cap</th>
            <th width="8%" style="text-align:center">Return</th>
            <th width="6%" style="text-align:center">WL</th>
            <th width="6%" style="text-align:center">Add</th>
          </tr>
          {% for stock in stock_list %}
        <tbody id="searchAstock">
          <tr>
            <td id="searchsymmol" style="border-bottom:1px;padding-left: 5px;"><a href="{% url 'stock_definition:detail' stock.id %}">{{stock.symbol}}</a></td>
            <td style="border:0px;"class="Ellipsis Company">{{stock.company_name}}</td>
            <td data-type="{{stock.sector}}">{{stock.sector}}</td>
            <td>{{stock.streak}}</td>
            <td>{{stock.market_cap_rounded}}</td>
            <td>{% if 1w %}{{stock.five_day_avg}}{% elif 2w %}{{stock.ten_day_avg}}{% elif 3w %}{{stock.fifteen_day_avg}}{% else %}{{stock.change_percent}}{% endif %}</td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><a href="{% url 'stock_definition:add' stock.id %}"><img onclick="myFunctionWL" id="WLtest"src="{% static "Myimages/images/flag.png" %}" alt="" title="Add to Watchlist" height=20 width=20 style="border-radius:50%;"></img></a></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><a href="{% url 'myteam:add_to_template' template.id stock.id %}"><img src="{% static "Myimages/images/icon.png" %}" title="Add to my Team" height=20 width=20 style="border-radius:50%;"></img></a></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

And here are the scripts:

```
function myFunctionsearchbar() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("mySearchInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myTable1");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

var modal = document.getElementById("myModalAddaStock");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closeAddaStock")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I feel like there is a core concept I have missed about Javascript? My script was working just fine before I implement the modal ( those loops at the beginning of the HTML files ) and now it only works AFTER those loops are done...

Comment: where do you load your script?

Comment: just a sidenote in your html, you are using a for loop with the tbody opening inside causing your loop to repeatedly create a new tbody

Comment: Thank you for that sidenote Nick van der Waal, makes a lot of sense to move that! I am loading my script at the bottom just before </body>.